# What is the cause of the still reachable memory leak in C?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am getting a still reachable memory leak of 472 bytes here. I don't really know how to look for it as it says that it is in fopen_internal. So my question is.. does this mean that this leak is not in my user defined source code?

```
472 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==192077==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==192077==    by 0x48EF92D: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==192077==    by 0x48EF92D: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:86)
==192077==    by 0x10974E: create_log_process (logger.c:41)
==192077==    by 0x1094ED: open_db (sensor_db.c:21)
==192077==    by 0x1093C5: main (main.c:15)
==192077== 
==192077== LEAK SUMMARY:
==192077==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==192077==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==192077==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==192077==    still reachable: 472 bytes in 1 blocks
==192077==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

It is pointing to the code of this function:

```
int create_log_process() {
    // log file opening
    fp = fopen("gateway.log", "a");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error occurred during log file opening");
        exit(1);
    }
    // creation of communication and child process
    if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
        perror("Error occurred during pipe creation");
        fclose(fp);
        exit(5);
    };
    pid = fork();
    // error handle
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork failed");
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        fclose(fp);
        exit(2);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        close(fd[1]); // closing write_end.
        char received_message[BUFFER_SIZE];
        size_t message_length;
        while(read(fd[0], &message_length, sizeof(size_t)) > 0) {

            if ((read(fd[0], received_message, message_length)) < 0) {
                perror("An error occurred during reading from pipe");
                fclose(fp);
                close(fd[0]);
                exit(7);
            }
            printf("child process reads: %s \n", received_message);

            // timestamp creation.
            time_t timer;
            time(&timer);
            struct tm *timestamp_info;
            timestamp_info = localtime(&timer);
            char timestamp[20];
            strftime(timestamp, sizeof(timestamp), "%a %b %d %X %Y", timestamp_info);

            // writing message to log file.
            if (fprintf(fp, "%d - %s - %s\n", i++, timestamp, received_message) < 0) {
                perror("Error occurred during writing to log file");
                fclose(fp);
                close(fd[0]);
                exit(6); // error during writing to file
            }
            fflush(fp); // helps writing to log file without data to be buffered first.
        }
//        fclose(fp);
        close(fd[0]);
        exit(0); // success status.
    } else {
        close(fd[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is this leak mine, if so how do I fix this? do I need to close an opened file or deallocate some memory?
note: in the user defined code itself, I have not used a malloc anywhere.

Comment: It's not a leak -- the memory is still reachable and in use by the stdio library.

Comment: I mean, you never close `fp` in the code you show, and it is a global variable, so... that's it. But in any case "still reachable" memory is generally OK and not to be considered as a leak. You probably use `fp` in other functions and need it until program termination, so it's OK to not close it in that case.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli "still reachable" memory often suggests a memory leak. You need to investigate to determine that it's internal to a library like stdio and out of your control.

Comment: You've opened `fp` before the `fork`, so both the parent and the child have a copy of `fp`. If the child is the only process that's supposed to write to the log file, then the `fopen` should be after the `fork`, so that only the child has the file open. And the child should `fclose` the file before it exits.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks a lot for your help!

@user3386109: Indeed. I am fixing that immediately. What did you mean with your last sentence? I am closing the fclose file in an end_log_process function, but this was only executed by the parent process as the child process exits after done reading

Comment: @Barmar I don't really agree... "unreachable" memory definitely suggests a memory leak., but "still reachable" memory is pretty common and usually completely harmless, often just represents dynamically allocated resources that you need for the entire runtime and you can safely avoid freeing/destroying. Looking into a library is a complex and tedious process that you only need to investigate *after* you investigate your code, more often than not it is not the library that is the culprit.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking "unreachable".

Comment: In the child code, one of the `fclose` calls is commented out. So (assuming I'm reading the code correctly) the file is only closed if the child encounters an error.

Comment: *Amazing!* Thanks a lot for the help. The moving of the fopen() to the child process fixed the issue!
@user3386109 true. before that only the parent process was closing it in another function basically. but it is only needed inside of the logger process, as you mentioned.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli "usually completely harmless" Except when it isn't.

Comment: @user3386109 *the `fopen` should be after the `fork`*  No.  If the `fopen()` were to fail, the child process has no way to communicate that back to the parent process without a lot of code that's not needed.  It's much simpler to just call `fclose()` in the parent after calling `fork()` and leave a functional, reliable, and simple error handling process in place.

Comment: @dsdfs See my above comment.  You *had* error handling in the original implementation that allowed the parent process to immediately know that it didn't have an open log file.  You now don't have that.

Comment: @AndrewHenle so now it would always create the child process first and thus waste resources, correct?

Comment: @dsdfs No - if your child process can't open the log file, there's no reason for it to exist.  But if the child process does fail, how are you going to tell the parent process?  It's easier for the parent process to open the log file, and quit if it doesn't work.  Then after the `fopen()` call for the log file succeeds create the child process, which takes "ownership" of the `FILE` stream.  The parent process can then immediately `fclose()` the stream.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You communicate that back like any other error. What happens if the disk gets full after the first log line is written?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI So now OP has to code up interprocess communications?  When just doing the `fopen()` before the `fork()` makes that unnecessary?  Full disk?  Handle it like `syslog` does - wait for an admin to fix it.  What would you have the parent process do when it got notification the disk is full?  Try to log it?  Whatever you'd have the parent process do, the child process could do just as well - and without any need for interprocess communications

Comment: @AndrewHenle "What would you have the parent process do when it got notification the disk is full? " Exactly the same thing you want to do when the file  cannot be opened. If one is fatal, then is the other. If one can be ignored, then can be the other.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI  So a transient condition that can be alleviated by outside intervention is exactly the same as being denied access to a resource?  Even when the OPs code *expects* to *alway* be able to open a log file, but whether it runs out of space at some time in the future is a completely separate issue?  And you haven't yet justified the need for extraneous interprocess communications.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Some people want all errors in logging reported back to the main process, those people need IPC. Others don't need any errors in logging reported back, those don't need IPC. In either case `fopen` can be moved to the child (and replaced by some other mechanism if needed). You want errors in opening the log file reported back, but not any other errors (which BTW may or may not be transient). This is perhaps legit but it does seem unusual to me. BTW IPC is already happening, you just need another pipe for the opposite direction.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI You are proposing the OP change the way errors are handled in the original code posted to this question or be forced to implement interprocess communications just to support moving `fopen()` into the child.   Why?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Because the way errors are handled in the original code is inconsistent and may or may not be a result of a conscious decision. If any error happens in the child process, it just prints to stderr and exits. This has a nice side effect of sending SIGPIPE to the parent when it tries to log the next thing (that's a rudimentary IPC). Why not do the same thing with fopen and remove an extraneous error handling path?